# C++ storing rvalues in vector as pointer doesnt work when initialized outside of main()

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, static, rvalue

I have a class Parameter, in this class there is vector which stores pointers. I want to initialize this class with some values, but the pointers get invalidated when main() starts.

I dont want to copy the values inside the vector because the values can be very large.

But i also want to store lightweight objects like ints or bools.

When initializing the Parameter class outside main(), the pointers are no more valid. I understand what is the problem, but i dont have solution... Any ideas. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Parameter {
public:
    template <typename... TTail>
    Parameter(T&& value, TTail&&... values) :
        values { &value, &values... }
    {}

    void print() {
        for (auto value : values) {
            std::cout << *value << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    
    std::vector<T*>     values;
};

class Strategy {
public:
    static Parameter<int>   parameter1;
    static Parameter<int>   parameter2;
};

Parameter<int>  Strategy::parameter1(10, 20, 30);
Parameter<int>  Strategy::parameter2(50, 60, 70);

int main() {
    //  this doesnt work because the rvalues (10, 20, 30...) are going out of scope...
    //  and the saved pointers are no more valid
    //  when initialized outside main
    Strategy::parameter1.print();
    Strategy::parameter2.print();

    //  this works fine when initialized inside main
    Parameter   parameterA(100, 200);
    Parameter   parameterB(500, 600);
    parameterA.print();
    parameterB.print();
}
```

Comment: It "works" in `main` only because undefined behaviour is undefined, and sometimes gives the impression of working. Don't store pointers to temporaries.

Comment: If you want to store pointers inside `Parameter`, the pointed-to objects must outlive the corresponding `Parameter` instance. Example: `int a1[3]={10,20,30}; Parameter<int> Strategy::parameter1{a[0],a[1],a[2]};`.